# Meteor.Error Body cannot exceed 3000 characters

Tags: javascript, meteor, telescope

I am building a new application using **Telescope**, same as  ProductHunt. I imported new feed post from other sites such as http://gigaom.com/feed/,  in the admin settings panel.

In the browser console I executed `Meteor.call ('fetchFeeds')` code to test the feed's. But the feeds are not importing showing error in command prompt.

```
*Error [ Body cannot exceed 3000 characters][400].
error.Type :' Meteor.Error'*
```

How to overcome this please reply. It will be really helpfull. Thank you.

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306509/override-schema-defined-in-telescopemeteor

Answer (score 2):

If you feeds content is more than 3000 words, it will give you that error, cause you have a validation set on the Posts object for max length of 3000. You can update the below code in `telescope-posts` package [posts.js](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/5c9d9670d4c596a6577937e02f28c738369bd413/packages/telescope-posts/lib/posts.js#L63) to whatever validation you want or even remove it to let any amount of data to be imported..

```
/**
    Post body (markdown)
  */
  body: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    max: 3000,
    editableBy: ["member", "admin"],
    autoform: {
      rows: 5
    }
  }
```