# Override Schema defined in Telescope(Meteor)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, telescope

I am currently customizing Telescope heavily, which is written in Meteor.

I need to go over the 3,000 character defined in Telescope's `Posts` schema's `body` defined [here](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/packages/telescope-posts/lib/posts.js) in the source.

I've been able to customize the HTML and JS, but not the models. How would I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a file under your `lib` folder and use the documentation here: http://docs.telescopeapp.org/docs/custom-fields to remove or add fields to that Schema.

**EDIT**: Sorry, but reading carefully your comment I understood you want to modify the autoForm props rather than the Schema itself. To change the maximum allowed value, do something along these lines:

```
Posts.removeField("body");
Posts.addField({
  fieldName: 'body',
  fieldSchema: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    max: 5000,
    editableBy: ["member", "admin"],
    autoform: {
      placeholder: 'Cannot exceed the maximum length of 5000 characters',
      row: 10,
      type: 'textarea'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've been able to add custom fields, it's more about overriding the current condition of 3,000 character limit.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I did with "I need to go over the 3,000 character defined in Telescope's Posts schema". Thanks for the answer though!